# How to iterate through all rows and save the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Python script to do some steps.
Right now everything is working except the part that it has to go through all table rows and save each line as a JSON object. The problem is: It only saves the last line. So it's not saving the previous lines. I know where is the problem but don't know how to fix.

Here is the code:

```
url = 'http://website.com/group1.html'
htmlFile= urlopen(urlGroup1)
soup= BeautifulSoup(htmlGroup1, 'html.parser')

table = soup2.find_all("table", {"class": "sortable employeeList result-table"})[0]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
Filegroup1 = open('group1.csv', 'wt+')
Datagroup1 = csv.writer(Filegroup1)
jsonFilePath = r'group1.json'
def make_json(Filegroup1, jsonFilePath):
    data2 = {}
    with open('group1.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader:
            data2 = rows
            
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(simplejson.dumps([data2], indent=4))

try:
    for row in rows:
        FilteredRow = []
        for cell in row.find_all(['td', 'th']):
            FilteredRow.append(cell.get_text().strip())
        Datagroup1.writerow(FilteredRow)
finally:
    Filegroup1.close()
    make_json(Filegroup1, jsonFilePath)
```

The issue is here:

```
for rows in csvReader:
    data2 = rows
```

If I change it to the following, it will work!! But it will group each object by Employee ID. Which I don't want that.

```
for rows in csvReader: 
    key = rows['Employee Name']
    data3[key] = rows
```

Comment: Instead of `data2 = rows` did you mean to do `data2.update(rows)`? Or make `data2` be a list instead of a dict, and do `data2.append(rows)`? A list _is_ valid json, after all.

Comment: Make it a list. I tried append, didn't work tho..